# threeparttable: How to write tablenotes in \Alph letter format?

Tags: threeparttable, tablenotes

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{ccX}
                Value   & Text  & Author \\\hline
                5       & Bla   & \tnote{1}\\\hline
            \end{tabularx}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[1] {This is the tablenote}
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

I want to let the `tablenotes` appear as `\Alph` letters in normal font of current text line instead of `\textsuperscript` mode. The config should be valid just locally for this single table and not globally. How to do so?

Either `\begin{threeparttable}[online]` nor `\begin{tablenotes}[online]` did work like expected.

---

**Update:** Also the "source" letter in the table itself should be in normal text mode, not only the `tablenote`.

Comment: erh, the note numbers in threeparttable are all manual, if you want A,B,C, just use `\tnote{A}` and `\item[A]`. To not have it as superscript inside the notes, add this right after `\begin{table}`: `\def\TPTnoteLabel#1{#1\hfil}`

Comment: `\begin{tablenotes}[online] \item[A] ...`  works fine for me.

Comment: @daleif: Not only the letters inside `tablenotes` should be in normal text mode, but also the "source" letter in the table itself. Sorry, I explained it badly.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, that works. :-) But I also need the source letter in the table itself in normal text mode. Sorry for missunderstanding!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a new command for that. I added a thinspace and a pair of parentheses to distinguish it from the rest of the cell content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\def\Tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\,\TPTtagStyle{(#1)}}}%
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}}%
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{ccX}
                Value & Text & Author \\\hline
                5 & Bla & Blah\Tnote{A}\\\hline
            \end{tabularx}
            \begin{tablenotes}[online]
                \item[A] {This is the tablenote}
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) No worries, I just want to use this in one table to specify the source author with a `\Alph` letter because their names would be too long for the table column.

Comment: If it is for this, may I suggest you to take a look at the `copyrightbox` package?